How to find a list of polygons from one layer that intersects a polygon in another layer
I have two layers with polygons. Layer A has polygons that are contiguous and cover the entire geography. Layer B has individual polygons that are not contiguous and intersect more than one polygon from layer A.
How do I create a spatial join file that lists each polygon from layer A and shows which polygon from layer B (if any) intersects? Ideally, the output would be something like this:

I have tried the MMQGIS spatial join tool but that does not work for this type of problem.

Look at the Overlap Analysis tool.

You can create a Virtual Layer using the query:
SELECT  row_number() over () as id,
        a.polyid as "polygon-a", 
        b.polyid as "polygon-b", 
        a.geometry
FROM apolygons AS a
LEFT JOIN bpolygons as b
ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
ORDER BY a.polyid

The query joins each polygon from the second layer (in my case named bpolygons) to the polygons in the first layer (apolygons).
Replace polyid with the names of your id columns in each layer and apolygons and bpolygons with your layer names.


Use the Union tool from the QGIS tool box, if you only want the list of intersecting polygons, then delete the rows with null values on the fields from layer B, to do that select by expression by clicking the  icon in the attribute table dialog and write an expression like this "Field from layer B" IS NULL, then click the delete selected features icon (). The result will look like this:

